# Generate txt file under /resources and immediatelly read it without rebuilding the app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a rather simple question. I have a controller with two endpoints

```
/newFile
/downloadFile/{fileName}
```

`/newFile` endpoint creates a simple `.txt` file under resources

and my expectation would be to hit `/downloadFile/{fileName}` and download the newly created resource.

```
Resource res = new ClassPathResource(fileName);
```

so as it turned out classpath resource looks under `build/resources` and the file is not yet there (because I haven't restarted/rebuild the app, once I do it - I can download the file) but the whole idea is to dynamically generate files and access them immediately - is there a quick way to bypass this without having to rebuild?

Comment: No, it is from spring-boot - org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem when I was working on FACE Recognition API which has the same process of creating a file and and uploading it to analysis.

What java does is It abstracts project to JVM and runs on it, So your newly created file won't be in the JVM, What you need to do is to use a Database or any cloud storage or NFS.

According to my perspective Using Database is the best option. [Code Java How to upload files to database with Servlet, JSP and MySQL](https://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql) and [Javatpoint store file in Oracle database](https://www.javatpoint.com/storing-file-in-oracle-database) are some documents you can refer for using a database.

you can refer to [this document](https://o7planning.org/en/10839/uploading-and-downloading-files-from-database-using-java-servlet) for implementing your project.